# how to extract class name and its properties from json text in angular?

Tags: json, angular

I am new to angular and my internship demands dealing with a lot of json texts and files. 
The json i'm currently working on looks like this (it represents a class) :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "cin": "string",
    "age": "int"
  }
}
```

the angular project reads the json text from a textarea therefore the name and the properties can change.

I need to extract the name of the class and its attributes separetly each time i hit the submit button .

```
        <form  #json="ngForm" >
            <textarea placeholder="paste your json file in here" rows="15" cols="150"></textarea>
            <button (click)='sendJson(json)'> submit </button>
        </form>
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Show us sendJson method code that you have already tried.

Comment: use the javascript function JSON.parse(). It's possible you need remove spaces and return from your text. use RegExpr to remove it

Comment: ```` sendJson(json){
    console.log("youp")
    console.log(json);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    this.http.post("https://localhost:44333/api/values/sendjson", json.value).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log("done");
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );
  } ````

Comment: I tried everything just to get a simple result, it is sending it to an asp.net back-end

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not entirely sure what your asking but you can simply use and `[(ngModel)]` to track the changes made and save it to a variable.

**.TS**

```
jsonChanges: string;
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="jsonChanges" placeholder="paste your json file in here" rows="15" cols="150"></textarea>
```